# associations in ember js

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ember.js

I have two models **Users** and **Recipes**. User can create recipe and user can add recipe to favorites.

In rails I have such associations in User model with the Favorites model(user_id,recipe_id).
I've already got favorites user recipes. How can i get  recipes that were created by current user?

```
has_many :favorites
has_many :recipes
has_many :recipesbox, through: :favorites, source: :recipe
```

When I'm trying to make this in Ember js I have trouble.

user_serializer.rb

```
class UserSerializer < ActiveModel::Serializer
  attributes :id, :name, :email
  has_many :recipes, embed: :ids
  has_many :recipesbox, through: :favorites, embed: :ids
end
```

user.js.coffee

```
App.User = DS.Model.extend
  name: DS.attr('string')
  email: DS.attr('string')
  recipes: DS.hasMany('App.Recipe')
```

recipe.js.coffee

```
App.Recipe = DS.Model.extend
  user: DS.belongsTo('App.User')
  title: DS.attr('string')
```

user.hbs

```
<h1>{{name}}</h1>
<p><b>Email:</b> {{email}}</p>
<h3>Favorites</h3>
{{#each recipe in recipes}}
  <div>
    <span>{{recipe.id}}</span>
    <span>{{recipe.title}}</span>
  </div>
{{/each}}
```

My serialized user is:

```
{
  user: {
    id: 1,
    name: "ejiqpep",
    email: "ejiqpep@gmail.com",
    recipe_ids: [
      4,
      5
    ],
    recipesbox_ids: [
      4,
      1,
      2,
      3
    ]
  }
}
```

Comment: what exactly is it that doesn't work? with your current question i can only guess and suggest that you change `has_many :recipesbox, through: :favorites, embed: :ids` in your `UserSerializer` to `has_many :favourites, through: :favorites, embed: :ids` (just to avoid pluralization trouble for now) and add `favourites: DS.hasMany('App.Recipe')` to your `User` model. also, you may need to add `:include => true` to the `has_many` lines in the `UserSerializer` at some point depending on what you want to do.

Comment: The problem is that i don't know how to get one more has_many in user.js.coffee for favorites.

Comment: what about: `favorites: DS.hasMany('App.Favorite')` and then respectively the model `App.Favorite = DS.Model.extend({..});`

Comment: I posted my comment as an answer, so you can accept and upvote it :) thanks

Answer (score 0):

what about

```
App.User = DS.Model.extend
  name: DS.attr('string')
  email: DS.attr('string')
  recipes: DS.hasMany('App.Recipe')
  favorites: DS.hasMany('App.Favorite')
```

and then respectively the model

```
App.Favorite = DS.Model.extend({..});
```